# Hoisting with Functions order

Tags: javascript

I have this situation

```
var fellowship = undefined;

fellowship = function(){
    return "broken";
  };

 function fellowship(){
    return "friends";
 }

console.log(fellowship);
```

The function that returns "friends" is never reached, even if I call it like this:

```
console.log(fellowship());
```

Can anyone explain me how the function can be called?

Comment: The question is *why* do you have that situation in the first place?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is interpreted as if it looked like this:

```
 function fellowship(){
    return "friends";
 }

var fellowship = undefined;

fellowship = function(){
    return "broken";
  };

console.log(fellowship);
```

Thus, the declaration of a variable named "fellowship" overwrites the binding of that symbol to the function defined with the same name. You can't call it after that point.

Answer (score 3):

> *"Can anyone explain me how the function can be called?"*

It can't be called. You've overwritten it. There's no way for a single identifier to directly reference two different values.

Function declarations will always lose in a contention with an assignment expression in the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

Yes here the concept of variable hoisting and function declaration hoisting is coming into picture.
In your example, you have declared

```
var fellowship = undefined;
```

already at the top.
Now the next statement:

```
 fellowship = function() {
        return "broken";
    }
```

is an expression which is not hoisted in javascript.
And the third one is function declaration which on the line of variable hoisting is also hoisted.
So, now your structure becomes something like:

```
var fellowship = undefined;

// function declaration hoisted
function fellowship(){
    return "friends";
}

fellowship = function(){
    return "broken";
};
```

So, when you are calling fellowship(), it returns 'broken'.

http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/
thi link should be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, function definitions are hoisted to the top of the current scope. Your example code therefore reads as:

```
var fellowship= function() { return 'friends' };
var fellowship= function() { return 'broken' };
```

if u want info about this follow this link:
http://www.adequatelygood.com/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting.html